# PDFBox Pdf to Image losing QR Code "ColorSpace Pattern doesn't provide a non-stroking color"

Tags: java, pdf, qr-code, pdfbox

Similar to this SO [PDFBox - PDF to Image losing barcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22028433/pdfbox-pdf-to-image-losing-barcode)

The PDF in question: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B13zTPQR9uxscXRMWjhsZ0doa00/view?usp=sharing

There is minimal text, and a medium sized QR Code. I have tried many different solutions to convert this PDF page to an image using PDFBox/ImageIO, but so far the QR Code is always missing from the result.

When I use PDFBox's PDFImageWriter I get this log:

`ColorSpace Pattern doesn't provide a non-stroking color, using white instead!`

I'm thinking that pertains to the QR Code.

Is this expected behavior? Can someone else confirm PDFBox cannot copy the QR Code from this PDF? Is there any way to convert this to an image using Java or PDFBox?

Comment: Your PDF has restricted access. What I can already tell you is that patterns aren't supported in 1.8.*, but they will be in the 2.0 version.

Comment: so the `ColorSpace Pattern doesn't provide a non-stroking color, using white instead!` signifies that PDFBox is finding a "pattern" on the source PDF? Is that different from an "image"? It's a print off from a webpage that had a QR Code and some text on it. I'll try to resolve the restricted access

Comment: I've updated the share-link. It should work now.

Comment: The QR-Code is an image that is part of a pattern. This is of course silly, because it could have been done directly as an image in the PDF, but that is how the creator of that PDF did it.

Comment: How could you tell it is `an image that is part of a pattern`? Also... what is the timeframe of `2.0` :) ? Six months off? One year off? Three? In the mean time I think I'll need to use Ghost4J to convert this PDF to an image, unless you have some other ideas.

Comment: I used PDFDebugger. The timeframe is a few months. (hopefully - we're all volunteers). Ghost4J sounds like an excellent idea. Ghostscript is a very good product. I've used their testfiles to uncover errors in PDFBox :-)

Comment: thanks to you and all the other PDFBox committers for your work and engagement in SO!

Comment: @TilmanHausherr hello, I just realized that Ghost4J is not friendly in threaded environments, which is how I would use it... now I'm getting desperate... do you know of any (preferably Java) open-souce/free libs that can convert a PDF to image such as the one in this question, excluding GhostScript? I trust your advice and I've been searching to no avail. If no free ones, any commercial suggestion?

Comment: Like I said, PDFBox can do it, but only the trunk version, i.e. it's more work (build from source, or get snapshot libraries, and read about the API from the source examples). Commercial products with free evaluations are ICEPdf and JPedal. ICEPdf has a free version but it isn't good with fonts.

Comment: Until PDFBox 2.x is more stable... I checked out the less discussed (for some reason?) PDF-Renderer and did [similar to this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21064270/how-to-increase-the-resolution-of-image-in-pdf-renderer#answer-21071630) to convert PDF to image. It seems to work